# Vectors header file in DosBox

Tags: c++, dosbox

I am using DosBox 0.74 and I want to use vectors function, but I can't locate its header file ? its not `<vector.h>` nor `<vector>`. I tried it with Visual Studio and it was working fine.
It has a different name in DosBox or what ?
Please help me, since I have to submit my work with DOSBox.

Comment: DOSBOX ? are you using TurboC++ ?

Comment: Yes, TurboC++ (DOSBox 0.74)

Comment: yeah :D I use Visual Studio most of the time but I have to submit my assignment in University using DOSBox :c

Comment: Erm what? Is that an actual requirement of the source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vectors were implemented in C++ after Turbo C++. In fact, C++ (as the standardised language we know it today) didn't *exist* until after Turbo C++! It is a truly ancient IDE and anyone would recommend not to use it. It's better to use IDEs of this century.

So, there are no STL libraries like `<vector>` in Turbo C++.

Simply put, you can't use vectors in Turbo C++. If you really want to, then you will have to create a library for it yourself (but it won't be worth it).

You said that you have Visual Studio; stick to that. And if you want, you can use Code::Blocks. Just stop using Turbo C++.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I will request my teacher to allow us working with Visual Studio instead of this old DOSBox. @arun thanks!

Comment: @SyedRafay , Happy to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be Open Watcom C/C++. It has STL and it can compile for Dos, which to my knowledge current versions of Visual Studio cannot do. I use it with DOSBox for unit testing embedded software in a 16-bit environment.