# how to make an array of variable size in c++ in tubo c++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

How can I write a variable sized array...for instance

```
int n;
n=10;
int arr[n];
```

now, that won't compile on my compiler (turbo c++). can anyone help me and tell me how I can create an array that is of a variable size?
my compiler gives the error that it cant convert int into int* (i.e, it cant convert the x into the array[x])

Comment: write a template class that will new/delete/realloc on demand ...

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, you can't create a VLA in C++ (though some toolchains support it as an extension via their C functionality; not yours).

And, since [your toolchain is too old to have vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29329867/560648), you're stuck with `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Try to encourage your school to move on from the 1980s.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to declare a fixed size array of size 10 here. However, the size needs to be a compile constant. So you need to do this:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n];
```

But if you only know the size at run time, you need to dynamically allocate the array. For that you do this:

```
int *arr = new int[n];
```

You must remember to deallocate the array with delete [] arr.

Better to use a std::vector, which will take care of the memory allocation and deallocation for you.

Comment: Turbo-c++ doesn't have a `std::vector` implementation.